# Can I make a select type="file"?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Ok, So I need to implement a drop-down where I can choose some file from a folder directory. I already have the dropdown displaying the files but when I'm making the query I'm getting this error `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError:'xxxxxx'` I'm not sure if is even passing the whole file or just the name of the file. Can I do something as a `<select type="file">`? or can I connect an hidden input type="file" to the select? Thanks

Comment: How are you populating the select with files from the users computer?

Comment: Is not from the user computer, is from a server folder, I have a python script that does the query

Comment: Then it is not a file input since the user is not uploading a file. What are you intending to do with the selected file?

Comment: the user doesn't have direct access to the server folder, so they should be able to choose a file from a drop-down, that is going to be uploaded into the software to be converted from .xlsx to .csv

Answer (score 1):

Your dropdown should just be a list of file names which you can then convert into paths when cleaning the input

```
class FileSelectForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.ChoiceField(choices=list_of_files)

    def clean_file(self):
        file_name = self.cleaned_data['file']
        file_path = ...  # You'll need to convert the name to a full path here
        return open(file_path)
```

Now when your form is submitted and is valid you will have an open file object for the selected file in your cleaned data

```
form = FileSelectForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.cleaned_data['file']  # This will be a file object
```